# How can I exclude PATTERN from inotify/incron

Tags: linux, inotify

I'm using incron to watch for events in a directory but I want to exclude some subdirectory or some filename PATTERNS.

Is there a way I can do this elegantly?

Comment: Can you be more specific? incron 0.59 doesn't support monitoring subdirectories. Do you want to ignore events regarding directories and listen only to events related with files?

Comment: Let's say I just want to exclude *.pyc and *.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incron doesn't support pattern filters, so you'll need to implement your own.

A simple example for just one file extension could be:

Incrontab:

```
/watched/directory IN_ALL_EVENTS /usr/local/bin/incronfilter .pyc $# /bin/echo $@/$# $& $%
```

incronfilter:

```shell
#!/bin/bash

ext=$1
file=$2
shift 2

[ "$file" == "${file%$ext}" ] &&  $*
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. It took me a while to realise that incron passes information to $@, $#, $%, $& :)

Comment: Apparently I failed to RTFM: http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en

Comment: Anyone could suggest me the syntax to exclude subdirectories?